# How can I substitute any numeric value for argument in this.function.bind(this)

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind

```
class hoge{
    constructor(key) {
        this.Idx = require("./myIndex.json");
    }
    foo(id, concepts){
        var aFunction = {
            "one": this.selectAction.bind(this),
            "two": this.selectAction.bind(this)
    }
    selectAction(id, concepts, number){
        return (id + concepts + this.Idx[number])

    }

}
```

How can I substitute any numerical value for only one argument of number in this.selectAction.bind(this) in aFunction method?
 For example, 
 "one": this.selectAction.bind(this, number = 0);
 "two": this.selectAction.bind(this, number = 1);

If I write like this, return this error

`ReferenceError: number is not defined`

Comment: you can't use bind like that (besides the obvious syntax error) - see the [documentation for bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to learn how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [bind documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind) you have to pass arguments in order.

```
class hoge{
    constructor(key) {
        this.Idx = require("./myIndex.json");
    }
    foo(id, concepts){
        var aFunction = {
            one: this.selectAction.bind(this, id, concepts, 1),
            two: this.selectAction.bind(this, id, concepts, 2)
    }
    selectAction(id, concepts, number){
        return (id + concepts + this.Idx[number])
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I misunderstand arguments of function bind. My code be able to run successfully.